# converting text file to python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having issues converting a text file to a python dictionary. Fortunately, the text file has a ":" that divides my future key with its value. For example, every row is structured like this "-Project Manager: John Caldwell". Id like to loop through a directory that contains numerous text files. In the process id like to strip away a '-' that each row has. Here is the code that i have so far:

```
import sys, traceback,os, csv, itertools
from collections import defaultdict

def get_metadata(filepath):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for files in filepath:
        if files.endswith(".txt"):
            with open(files,'r') as in_file:
                for line in in_file:
                    k,v = line.strip('-').split(':')
                    d[k].append(v)

    return d

root_directory = get_metadata("C:\Random")
print root_directory
```

This is what i get when i run the script

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {})
```

Comment: As a side note, don't use unescaped backslashes in non-raw string literals.  You happen to get away with it here, but try it with `"C:\random"` and you'll get a nasty surprise. You can use a raw string (`r"C:\Random"`), escape your backslashes (`"C:\\Random"`), or (except in rare cases) use forward slashes instead (`"C:/Random"`).

Comment: Also, your values are going to end up with newlines on the end. You may want `line.rstrip().lstrip('-').split(':')` or similar to take care of that.

Comment: @abarnert I am getting this as an error:  ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: The `ValueError` looks like a new problem that you'll want to create a new question for if you can't solve it yourself. But I'll give 50/50 odds that the problem is just that you have blank lines somewhere in the file (maybe just one at the end), and trying to `split` a blank line into `k` and `v` is obviously going to fail. You can handle that by checking for empty lines (`if strippedline: k, v = strippedline.split(':')`), or by using a `try`/`except`, or a couple other ways, depending on whether you just want to silently ignore empty lines, or anything unexpected, or…

Comment: One more thing: you may want to `strip` the `v` and maybe `k` values as well; otherwise, you're going to end up with a project manager named `" John Caldwell"` instead of `"John Caldwell"`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `"C:\Random"` isn't a list of files, it's just a string. So, `for files in filepath` gives you `'C'`, then `':'`, then `'\'`, and so on. None of those end in `.txt`, so you don't open any files or do anything else.

What you want is probably [`for files in os.listdir(filepath):`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir).

Or, if you want to open all files in that directory or any subdirectories (recursively), use [`walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) (see the linked docs for sample code).

As bgporter points out, if the only reason you're calling `listdir` is to then check each filename against a pattern, you may want to use [`for files in glob.glob(os.path.join(filepath, '*.txt')):`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) to skip the need for the `if` test.

Comment: ...or use `glob.glob()` to just get a list of the .txt files that are of interest...

Comment: Great feedback! Id assume the part where i convert txt to dictionary is correct? Its giving me a ValueError
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: @user40720: The rest of it looks fine. For the `ValueError` see my comment on the question.